# How to use func to quickly add specific comments to certain lines of a file？

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, functions

I wrote a function, the function is used to add comments to some lines, the content is as follows:

```
func Add(x)
  call setline(a:x+1, "\  //**************************************************************")
  call setline(a:x+2, "\  // **** Note ****")
  call setline(a:x+3, "\  //**************************************************************")
endfunc
```

When I use the Add(100) function in vi, I want the content of the 100th line to remain unchanged, and 3 additional lines are used to add text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `append()` function instead as described in `:h setline()` help section.

It accepts the line number and and either a text line or a list of text lines that would be inserted/appended after given line number.

```
func! AddCommentHeader(lnum) abort
    let comment_header = 
                \[
                \'//******************************************************',
                \'//******* Note *****************************************',
                \'//******************************************************'
                \]
    let lnum = a:lnum < 1 ? line('.') : a:lnum

    call append(lnum, comment_header)
endfunc

nnoremap gci :<C-U>call AddCommentHeader(v:count)<CR>
```

In the example above there is a function that accepts a line number to insert a comment header after. If the line number is 0 or basically less then 1 it would insert comment header right after the current line:

```
let lnum = a:lnum < 1 ? line('.') : a:lnum
```

This is ternary operator `condition ? return if true : return if false`.

The mapping after function maps `gci` to call a function. There are 2 interesting things there `<C-U>` and `v:count`:

- we would like to provide a count you prepend your mapping with to a function, like if I want to add comment header after line 100 I would do `100gci` -- this is what built-in `v:count` variable for.
- we don't want default range to be applied to our function which we call from within commandline mode `:call ...` if we provide a count for it. Try for example to type `100:` and see your command line is prefilled with `:.,.+99` <--- this thing we delete with `<C-U>` in the mapping:

```
    nnoremap gci :<C-U>call AddCommentHeader(v:count)<CR>
```

PS

Don't forget to use `K` mapping to call builtin help on a function under cursor.
Also `:h function-list` might be useful.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful, thank you very much.